Fourier Transformation of Heaviside Function
Let be $H(x)$ Heaviside function. I want to show that $H$ defines a tempered distribution and compute is Fourier transformation.
The exercise has two steps:

I have alredy proof that $\xi\left(i\hat{H}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}v.p.\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$ in $\mathcal{S}^{'}$.
Now the next step is to obtain that:
$$i\hat{H}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}v.p.\frac{1}{x}=c\delta$$ in $\mathcal{S}'$ for some constant $c$ . This is what I don't know how to see.

I've think in use the multipolar expansion using that the left side has finite support, but then I don't know that to do with the other derivatives of Dirac delta or how to elimite $\xi$.
Any help will be apreciate. Thanks

You can rule out other derivatives of Dirac delta by homogeneity ;)

You haven't seen a theorem that $xu=0$ has solutions $u=c\delta$?
